# Date time format in Spring

Tags: java, spring, date, datetime

I want to get the current date and time in Spring and format it. I use LocalDateTime to get the current date, but it is like this:  `2021-08-23T18:24:36.229362200`

And want to get it in this format: `"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a`"
I tried this:

```
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(); //ziua de azi
    String d = localDateTime.toString();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM//dd//yyyy h:mm a");
    localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(d, formatter);
```

But I get the following error:

> Text '2021-08-23T18:26:37.002166200' could not be parsed at index 2

Please how can I format it?

Comment: You want `String display = formatter.format (localDateTime) ` and print that.

Comment: Since you want to format and since both your `DateTimeFormatter` and your `LocalDateTime` have methods named `format` — don’t call the method named `parse` since parsing is the opposite operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.now()
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu h:mm a" )   
)
```

Or, better to be explicit rather than rely implicitly on defaults. And perhaps better to automatically localize.

```java
ZonedDateTime
.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Bucharest" )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ) 
    .withLocale( 
        new Locale( "ro" , "RO" )   // Romanian in Romania.
    )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KzybVg).

> 24.08.2021, 04:09

Using `Locale.US` instead produces:

> 8/24/21, 4:11 AM

## Details

I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do. That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset, so it cannot represent a specific moment in time.

To represent a moment, a specific point on the time line, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

To capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or specify a zone. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Let *java.time* automatically localize for you.

```java
Locale locale = new Locale( "ro" , "RO" ) ;  // For Romanian in Romania. Or `Locale.US`, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatSyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Or you can hard-code a specific format. Do not use pairs of slash characters as seen in Question.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu h:mm a" ) ;
```

I see nothing specific about *Spring* in your Question or code. These are general Java issues.

Comment: Good answer! A couple of comments: (1) `DateTimeFormatter` is `Locale`-sensitive and therefore `Locale` should always be specified with `DateTimeFormatter`. The am/pm marker is typically `Locale`-sensitive. (2) It will be useful to newbies if you also mention [`LocalDateTime now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) as an alternative to `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId)`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Good point about locale. I sense that the OP may want `Locale.forLangaugeTag("ro")` (*ziua de azi* in the comment according to Google Translate is Romanian for *present day*).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Regarding # 1, I did so in the detailed section further down. For the *tl;dr* section, I tend to use minimal code, to communicate the basic idea. But in this case, prompted by your Comment, I added a second example code using explicit time zone and locale.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Regarding # 2, I think it better to advise *never* using `LocalDateTime.now`. (a) I suspect programmers rarely understand what that call means, that they are intentionally omitting the context of zone/offset. And even if they do understand, making a habit of that could lead to faulty code some day. (b) I have yet to conceive of a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is actually helpful. Making it easier to be lazy in generating shorter strings does not count as “helpful” in my book.

Comment: @OleV.V. Nice catch on the detection of Romanian. I added time zone & locale to match. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a");
String formattedDate = localDateTime.format(formatter);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```